# QueryDSL (JPA) dayOfYear, dayOfMonth translation to hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm getting an exception when running this java code:

```
List<Tuple> companies2accLoginCount = accoutLoginCountQuery
                    .listDistinct(new QTuple(QCompany.company1.id, QAccountLogin.accountLogin.loginDatetime.dayOfMonth().countDistinct()));
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 48 [select distinct company1.id, count(distinct day(accountLogin.loginDatetime))
from de.workxl.cxlbackend.database.model.Company company1
  left join company1.accounts as account
  left join account.accountLogins as accountLogin
where accountLogin.loginDatetime > ?1
group by company1.id
having count(distinct day(accountLogin.loginDatetime)) >= ?2]
```

The same with *dayofyear*. It seems something else than a left bracket is expected after dayofyear or dayofmonth.

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.2 and QueryDSL 2.9.0

**update:** I've just managed to migrate the project to QueryDSL 3.2.3 (had to upgrade spring-data-commons to 1.6.1 and spring-data-jpa to 1.4.1 as well) but the exception persists.

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Querydsl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Hibernate's parser. This works with EclipseLink.